# Combinatorics. Use of multisets?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose there are 12 red sweets and 12 green sweets. In how many ways can the sweets be distributed so that each of the five children gets at least one sweet of each colour?

---

My attempt involved splitting this up into two subproblems; one that involves red sweets and one that involves green sweets.
  For the red sweets, I distributed one sweet to each of the five children first since they "at least" receive one. Then, I use the multiset formula of $${n+k-1\choose{k-1}},$$ for $n=7$ and $k=5$. Evaluating this gives $${11\choose{4}}=330.$$ The answer for the green sweets gives the same. But then, when combining the two; do I square the quantities to get $330^2$ or is it instead $2\cdot 330$?

Comment: You do multiply.  However, if there are $12$ sweets of each color, why are you using $n = 7$?

Comment: Because each of them must have at least one sweet? So, having given each child a sweet each; I'm left with $7$? Also, why is it multiply instead of double?

Comment: If you give each child one of each then it boils down to the number of ways to put 14 things into 5 buckets.

Comment: My apologies.  I missed the sentence about first giving each child a sweet of each color.

Comment: @JohnDouma Ah, it's a lot simpler once I think of it like that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will multiply, because once you've picked a way to hand out red sweets you can now *independently* pick a way to hand out green sweets.

Incidentally, usually one would derive the formula for *nonnegative* integer solutions to an equation $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=k$ (i.e. counting multisets) from the formula for *positive* integer solutions. This is because in the positive integer case you can use "stars and bars" type reasoning. So passing back to the nonnegative case is slightly weird logic. It's still correct, though.

Comment: Personally, I learned how to solve the nonnegative case first, then learned the positive case.  I suppose what you learn first depends on the text or instructor.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Fair point. What was the reasoning you used for directly solving the nonnegative case without passing through the positive case?

Comment: In this case, I would have solved each subproblem in the positive integers, as it is easier in this context.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I don't mean in this problem, I just mean in general, what's the "direct" reasoning for counting nonnegative integer solutions to $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=k$, without bijecting them with the positive integer solutions to $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=k+n$?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question.  I suppose the first type of question I encountered was along the lines of "How many ways can six pencils be distributed to twelve children?"   Clearly, the problem cannot be solved in the positive integers since not every child can receive a pencil.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Real world examples make some combinatorics "bijection" tricks sound funny. Example: "How many ways can I distribute six pencils to twelve children? Well, pretend I had twelve more pencils and was forced to give at least one to each child..." and now the person you're talking to starts thinking you're nuts.